# meteor: how to stop asynchronous call?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to stop (kill) asynchronous Call?

In my app I have at client side sth like:

```
Meteor.call('doCalculation', function(err, result) {
  //do sth with result
});
```

'doCalculation' may take long time (this is ok) I dont want user to start new call when he/she has already one running call, I want to allow user to stop current call and submit new one. How correctly do this?

The only idea I have is to communicate between client and server using mongo. In some place in 'doCalculation' function I can observe some mongo document/collection and based on this do sth in the function (e.g. call exception). Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `semaphore` for this purpose. When the `semaphore` is 1, requests are allowed to be sent. When the `semaphore` is 0, requests are not allowed to be sent. The semaphore should be 1 by default and just before you send the request, you need to set it to 0. When a response is successful, you set the `semaphore` back to 1.

As about the timeout: You could use a time out using `setTimeout` after sending the request, like this:

```
if (semaphore) {
    var isTimedOut = false;
    var isSuccess = false;
    semaphore = 0; //No need to use var keyword, as this should be declared outside of this scope
    Meteor.call('doCalculation', function(err, result) {
        isSuccess = true;
        //do sth with result
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!isSuccess) {
            isTimeout = true;
            //do something else, to handle the time out state
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response but it is not answer to my question. 
I cannot set timeout, in this case there is no to long call. In same cases call may take few seconds (or less) in same other several minutes, both are ok. I do NOT want to force user to wait for the end of his/her job (as I wrote long job are in general correct and I cannot ban it). I do want user to be able to stop jobs.

Comment: @rmrmg once your browser has sent a request, it is sent. You cannot unsend it, as it is no longer on the computer in your control. The only thing you can do is to implement the callback in such a way that it would ignore responses arrived after the time out and to control the wait limit. This answer explains how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because you cannot generally set timeouts from the client's point of view. You don't need to, for a bunch of architectural reasons. The most important thing is that if you lose network connectivity or the server crashes (two cases timeouts are designed to manage), the client is aware immediately because it is disconnected. You can use `Meteor.status().connected` if this happens often.

It sounds like you're running a long calculation on the server. My suggestion is to return a `calculationId` immediately, and then update a collection with progress, e.g., `CalculationProgresses.update(calculationId, {$set: {progress: currentProgress}})` as you calculate. Your UI can then update the progress reactively, in the most convenient way possible.

Note, that when you do run long calculations on the server, you need to occasionally "yield," giving the chance for other work to happen. Node, on which Meteor is based, is tricky for long calculations if you don't master this notion of yielding. In Meteor, you can yield easily by updating a collection (e.g., your progress collection). This will solve lots of problems you're probably experiencing as you write your application.

Comment: regarding your comment about yielding, do Fibers solve that? i.e. would wrapping up the long-running operation in a Fiber solve the yield issue, or would it yield only the one time at its start? i would like to understand this better.

Comment: You can create a fiber for your long running operation (`Meteor.bindEnvironment` does this for you, as does `Meteor.async`). Inside a `MongoCollection::update`, there's eventually a call to `Fiber.yield()`, which is why updating a collection works too. Make sure to call `this.unblock()` in a method so that the client can make more requests.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a server-side solution for this. if you go with a client-side solution, you don't handle 2 cases:

1. the user reloads their browser
2. the user uses 2 browsers

i would create these methods:

1. isCalculationActive() -- this checks if the user already has a calculation active. on the server, you can either keep that fact in memory or write it to the db. on the client, if this returns false, then you can proceed to call doCalculation(). if true, you can give the user a popup or alert or something to ask if they want to cancel and proceed.
2. doCalculation() -- this cancels any outstanding calculation by that user and starts a new one.

with these implemented, the user can reload their browser w/o affecting either the running calculation or correct behavior. and if they try a 2nd browser, everything should still work as expected.

if you want to give the user the option to simply stop the job and not start a new one, then you can simply create:

3. cancelCalculation() -- this cancels any outstanding calculation by that user.